Allure results not generated in Cypress
I'm having trouble getting Allure results to generate in my Cypress project. Despite following the setup instructions, the allure-results directory remains empty after running my tests. Here are the details of my setup:
Configuration:
cypress.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const allureWriter = require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'z72d4i',
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      console.log('Initializing Allure plugin'); // Debugging message
      allureWriter(on, config); // Correctly initialize the Allure plugin
      console.log('Allure plugin initialized'); // Debugging message
      return config;
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://example.com',
    specPattern: 'cypress/e2e/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/index.js', // Enable the support file
    experimentalStudio: true, // Enable Studio mode
    reporter: 'spec', // Use the default spec reporter
    video: true, // Enable video recording
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true, // Enable screenshots on test failure
  },
});

cypress/support/index.js:
// This example support/index.js is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands';
// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands');
// Import the Allure plugin
import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin';
// Debugging message to ensure the plugin is loaded
console.log('Allure plugin loaded');
cypress/support/commands.js:
// cypress/support/commands.js
// Add custom commands here
// Debugging message to ensure commands.js is loaded
console.log('commands.js loaded');
// Example custom command (use a different name to avoid conflict)
Cypress.Commands.add('customLog', (message) => {
  console.log(message);
});

package.json:
{
  "name": "cypress-playground",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress run",
    "allure:report": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report",
    "allure:clear_results": "rm -rf allure-results",
    "allure:clear_report": "rm -rf allure-report",
    "precy-run": "npm run allure:clear_results && npm run allure:clear_report",
    "cy-run": "cypress run --env allure=true",
    "postcy-run": "npm run allure:report"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin": "^2.40.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.32.0",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^3.8.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.7"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

Steps to reproduce:
Run npm run cy-run to execute the tests.
Check the allure-results directory.
Expected behavior: The allure-results directory should contain the results of the tests.
Actual behavior: The allure-results directory is empty.
Additional information:
Cypress version: 13.16.1
Node version: v20.12.0
Allure plugin version: ^2.40.2
I've ensured that the directories have the correct permissions using:
chmod -R 777 /Users/myUser/Sites/Cypress/cypress-playground/cypress/allure-results
chmod -R 777 /Users/myUser/Sites/Cypress/cypress-playground/cypress/allure-report
Despite this, the results are not being generated. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you :)
